# web scraper too slow (what can i do to speed up my scraper?)

Tags: python, web-scraping

here is my code ..it is very slow I am not scraping a lot of data. My file size is 188 KB..i think the problem is i am getting all the internal url links from a website and scraping each one to find certain key words and count them. For each internal URL i have to make a request call so I end up scraping more websites than I have in the file.

I am thinking the solution should be deploying it to a virtual computer like AWS or is there anything I could do in my code to make it more efficient?

```
import re
# import xlwt
import time
import string
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from boilerpy3 import extractors
from urllib.parse import urlparse
# from urllib.parse import urljoin
# from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
# from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# downloads web page content
def get_web_page_content(page_url:str) -> object:
    response = None
    connection_status = True
    try:
        response = requests.get(page_url)
        time.sleep(5)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception('Web page response code is not 200.')
    except:
        connection_status = False
    return response, connection_status

# transforms HTML content into a BeautifulSoup object
def create_beautiful_soup_object(response:object) -> object:
    # '''
    # Takes a response object and returns a BeautifulSoup object
    # '''
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    return bs

# get page title
def get_page_title(bs:object) -> str:
    # '''
    # Takes a beautiful soup object and returns the page title
    # '''
    try:
        title = bs.title.text
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return title

# the subdirectory describes the document type
def extract_subdirectory(page_url:str) -> str:
    # '''
    # Takes a page URL and returns the subdirectory in the URL
    # '''
    # Defines the regex to match subdirectory in an URL
    regex = re.compile(fr"^(?:https:\/\/{page_url}\/|\/)(?P<subdirectory>(\w+-?)*)\/")
    match_obj = re.search(regex, page_url)
    if match_obj:
        subdirectory = match_obj.group('subdirectory')
        # replace - with a space
        rtn_value = subdirectory.replace('-', ' ')
    else:
        rtn_value = 'n/a'
    return rtn_value

def extract_text_data_from_web_page(web_content:str) -> string:
    # print("web_content", web_content)
    # '''
    # Takes a web content as an argument.
    # Returns a text string without clutter.
    # '''
    try:
        extractor = extractors.ArticleExtractor()
        return extractor.get_content(web_content)
    except:
        pass


# cleans text data. references: https://medium.com/nwamaka-imasogie/stand-up-comedy-and-nlp-c7d64002520c
def clean_text_data(raw_text:str) -> str:
    # print("str", str)
    rtn_value = ''

    try:
        rtn_value = raw_text
        # 1.    Make text all lower case
        rtn_value = rtn_value.lower()
        # 2.    Remove punctuation
        rtn_value = re.sub(r'[{}©]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)), '', rtn_value)
        # 3.    Remove numerical values
        rtn_value = re.sub(r'\w*\d+\w*', '', rtn_value)
        # 4.    Remove common non-sensical text
        rtn_value = re.sub(r' *\n *', ' ', rtn_value)
    except:
        pass

    return rtn_value


def is_absolute(url):
    return bool(urlparse(url).netloc)

# uses CountVectorizer in Python to count word frequencies
def count_word_frequencies(clean_text, name, turnover, size, employees, address, town, postcode, sic_code, directors, telephone, email, website):
    # print('clean_text', clean_text)

    word_frequency_dict = dict()

    list1 = clean_text.split()  # this is your original list of words
    print('list1', list1)
    word_frequency_dict["name"] = name
    word_frequency_dict["turnover"] = turnover
    word_frequency_dict["size"] = size
    word_frequency_dict["employees"] = employees
    word_frequency_dict["address"] = address
    word_frequency_dict["town"] = town
    word_frequency_dict["postcode"] = postcode
    word_frequency_dict["sic_code"] = sic_code
    word_frequency_dict["directors"] = directors
    word_frequency_dict["telephone"] = telephone
    word_frequency_dict["email"] = email
    word_frequency_dict["website"] = website

    word_frequency_dict["sustainability"] = list1.count('sustainability')
    word_frequency_dict["sustainable"] = list1.count('sustainable')
    word_frequency_dict["buffet"] = list1.count('buffet')
    word_frequency_dict["kitchen"] = list1.count('kitchen')
    word_frequency_dict["ISO 14001"] = list1.count('ISO 14001')
    word_frequency_dict["b corp"] = list1.count('b corp')
    word_frequency_dict["brasserie"] = list1.count('brasserie')
    word_frequency_dict["community"] = list1.count('community')
    word_frequency_dict["social"] = list1.count('social')
    word_frequency_dict["green credentials"] = list1.count('green credentials')
    word_frequency_dict["environment"] = list1.count('environment')
    word_frequency_dict["environmental"] = list1.count('environmental')
    word_frequency_dict["food"] = list1.count('food')
    word_frequency_dict["book a table"] = list1.count('book a table')
    word_frequency_dict["planet"] = list1.count('planet')
    word_frequency_dict["planet earth"] = list1.count('planet earth')
    word_frequency_dict["compostable"] = list1.count('compostable')
    word_frequency_dict["recyclable"] = list1.count('recyclable')
    word_frequency_dict["eco friendly"] = list1.count('eco friendly')
    word_frequency_dict["restaurant"] = list1.count('restaurant')
    word_frequency_dict["bistro"] = list1.count('bistro')
    word_frequency_dict["take away"] = list1.count('take away')
    word_frequency_dict["climate emissions"] = list1.count('climate emissions')
    word_frequency_dict["coffee"] = list1.count('coffee')
    word_frequency_dict["tea"] = list1.count('tea')
    word_frequency_dict["menu"] = list1.count('menu')
    word_frequency_dict["just eat"] = list1.count('just eat')
    word_frequency_dict["uber eat"] = list1.count('uber eat')
    word_frequency_dict["deliveroo"] = list1.count('deliveroo')
    word_frequency_dict["reservations"] = list1.count('reservations')
    word_frequency_dict["corporate social responsibility"] = list1.count('corporate social responsibility')
    word_frequency_dict["freshly squeezed juice"] = list1.count('freshly squeezed juice')
    word_frequency_dict["breakfast"] = list1.count('breakfast')
    word_frequency_dict["lunch"] = list1.count('lunch')
    word_frequency_dict["dinner"] = list1.count('dinner')
    word_frequency_dict["hotel"] = list1.count('hotel')
    word_frequency_dict["csr"] = list1.count('csr')
    word_frequency_dict["net zero"] = list1.count('net zero')
    word_frequency_dict["carbon offsetting"] = list1.count('carbon offsetting')
    word_frequency_dict["type"] = 'hospitality business'

    return word_frequency_dict


def get_response_text(internal_links):
    content = []

    for link in internal_links:
        try:
            response, status = get_web_page_content(link)
            time.sleep(5)
            print("response", response)
            print("status", status)
            if status == True:
                text_data = extract_text_data_from_web_page(response.text)
                clean_text = clean_text_data(text_data)
                print("clean_text", clean_text)

                content.append(clean_text)
        except:
            pass
    return content


# finds frequently words in the web page
def get_frequently_words(internal_links, name, turnover, size, employees, address, town, postcode, sic_code, directors, telephone, email, website):
    contents = get_response_text(internal_links)
    print("contents", contents)
    all_strings = list(map(str, contents))
    one_single_text = ' '.join(all_strings)
    dict_word_frequency = count_word_frequencies(one_single_text, name, turnover, size, employees, address, town, postcode, sic_code, directors, telephone, email, website)
    return dict_word_frequency

# finds a list of all internal links
def get_internal_links(soup, page_url):
    # '''
    # Takes a beautiful soup object and returns a list of all Internal links
    # '''
    # Initialize the return value
    rtn_value = list()
    # Defines the regex to find internal links. Hardcode the base URL
    regex = re.compile(fr'^((https:\/\/)?{page_url}\/|\/).+')
    links = soup.find_all('a', {'href': regex})

    if len(links) < 1:
        rtn_value.append(page_url)
        return rtn_value
    else:
        for link in links:
            try:
                href = link['href']

                if is_absolute(href):
                    rtn_value.append(href)
                else:
                    rtn_value.append(page_url + href)

            except AttributeError as e:
                pass

        if page_url not in rtn_value:
            rtn_value.append(page_url)

        return rtn_value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('./Endole.csv')

    name = df['Name'].to_list()
    turnover = df['Turnover'].to_list()
    size = df['Size'].to_list()
    employees = df['No. Of Employees'].to_list()
    address = df['Address'].to_list()
    town = df['Post Town'].to_list()
    postcode = df['Postcode'].to_list()
    sic_code = df['SIC Code'].to_list()
    directors = df['Directors'].to_list()
    telephone = df['Telephone'].to_list()
    email = df['Email Address'].to_list()
    website = df['Website'].to_list()

    page_urls = df['Website'].to_list()
    # print("NAMES", NAMES)
    # print("LINKS", LINKS)
    for i, page_url in enumerate(page_urls):
        # page_url = 'https://www.hotelanacapri.co.uk'
        response, status = get_web_page_content(page_url)
        print("response", response)
        print("status", status)
        if status == True:
            soup = create_beautiful_soup_object(response)
            page_title = get_page_title(soup)
            docuemnt_type = extract_subdirectory(page_url)
            internal_links = get_internal_links(soup, page_url)
            print("internal_links", internal_links)
            high_frequency_words = get_frequently_words(internal_links, name[i], turnover[i], size[i], employees[i], address[i], town[i], postcode[i], sic_code[i], directors[i], telephone[i], email[i], website[i])
            print("high_frequency_words", high_frequency_words)
            new_df = pd.DataFrame(high_frequency_words, index=[0])
            new_df.to_csv('testing.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: You can look at `multiprocessing` module to speed up your code. Also, consider refactoring `count_word_frequencies` function (to make it shorter and more mantainable).

Comment: which bit is slow? https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard python package **asyncio**. Most of the time you spend waiting for a response. Due to the large file size, this takes a long time. Asyncio allows you to run coroutines that will wait for a response. It is worth noting that you cannot use **requests** module with **asyncio**, since this library does not support asynchrony. You can look towards **aiohttp**

Another way is to use **multithreading**. In Python it doesn't quite work as you would expect due to the GIL, see more here: [What is the global interpreter lock (GIL) in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython)
However, Python's multi-threading allows you to run queries in parallel, so that should help you too.

Also you can use **multiprocessing**. You can run a separate process for each request, in which it will be processed.